# How do I copy my current website to VPS linux?

Tags: linux, hosting, vps

I have my current website on shared hosting. But recently we are shifting to VPS hosting. I am quiet new to this term and when I talked with their sales team about what is VPS and can I remotely connect to my machine using mstsc. They said the plan that I chose doesn't have that feature and for my budget, they can offer Linux VPS. Now the thing that confuses is how do I copy my existing website and move it there if they don't have any GUI? Do I have to type Linux commands for that?

Secondly, how do I open XML files and edit them. I know this sounds like a noob question but normally I am used to do mstsc for remote login. Can anybody explain me basic things of VPS and how do I get more help. I don't even know how to open a text or xml file in VPS.

Comment: If these are things you don't get, don't get a VPS. Or search someone that can do it for you.

Comment: Quit exactly. This i akin to saying "Hey, I bought a plane - how the heck do I start the engines now?". A VPS is a real server (virtual, still, it has bios, installs). If you do not know how to administrate a server, do not get one.

Comment: @Bart: Is there any tutorial regarding how do I get started with VPS linux?

Comment: @Downvote: So why a negative vote? Is this offtopic on this website? If I ask something that I don't know or I am doing it for 1st time people will come and start downvoting me?

Comment: @TimTom: I know this isn't as hard as starting a plane engine. I am sure given a day or two I will find it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @TomKaufmann Basically, what you're asking is, how do I administer Linux.  This is a broad topic.  From a certain point of view, it's likely as complicated as flying an airplane, but without the pressure of dying horribly if something goes wrong.

Comment: The faq states `Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.` I think there is a certain expectation here that you at least have know a little bit of what you're doing. Having set up plenty of Linux web servers myself and knowing what it takes to get one running... giving a realistic answer to your question could fill a book.

Comment: @cjc: that depends upon how to think. I don't think so. And moreover, I didn't ask anybody to teach me Linux. I just asked how do I edit simple xml file on VPS server and/or point to me few quick tutorials to help me get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HowtoForge has a ton of tutorials that will answer your questions. But as long as you are willing to learn and working in a terminal, you can learn system administration.

However, if you've never done it before, you might want to hire someone to administer your VPS or purchase a managed VPS, which is more costly than a non-managed VPS...